# Determine the value of N

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a complete n00b at math, but I'm wondering how one would go about determining the value of `n` in the following comparison.

`n * 1.5 + 12.5 = 12.5 / 2 + n`

I'm new to the math StackExchange, so I'm also not sure how to properly format this question. Feel free to edit.

$1.5n+12.5=\displaystyle \frac{12.5}{2}+n$

---

## Explanation

I don't think I formulated my mathematical equation properly because I know that the value I'm looking for is obviously a positive integer.

**I'm trying to figure out what size the squares must be, so that the center most square in each row is centered above or below the gap between the two squares in the other row.**

1. All the squares must be the same size.
2. All of the gaps are `12.5` pixels.

The squares in the image below are obviously not big enough as of right now.

[image]

Comment: okay i'll edit my answer. give me a couple minutes

Comment: From the image, it looks like subsequent rows of squares start from opposite sides of the black rectangle. Is that correct?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri correct, and both rows are "growing inwards" so to speak. likewise, the reason for the white lines is because i figured it would simplify the equation if u also didnt have to account for the gaps on the outer edges

Comment: @SakethMalyala ty sir! also, would this be considered algebra?

Comment: What is the distance between the white lines then?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri `295` pixels, but i was hoping for a general formula because in reality the `295` (and even the value of the gap) are also going to be variables

Comment: oh crap if you want it to be general let me cook up some variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the length of a gap be $g$ and the distance between the white lines be $l$. The distance of the left edge of the left square of the top row (in the image) from the white line on the left is$$n+\frac g2-\frac n2=\frac{n+g}2$$Adding to this the length of the $k$ squares in the top row and the $(k-1)$ gaps between them,$$\frac{n+g}2+kn+(k-1)g=l\\\implies\left(k+\frac12\right)n+\left(k-\frac12\right)g=l\\\therefore n=\frac{l-\left(k-\frac12\right)g}{k+\frac12}$$For finding $n$, just substitute the value of $k$.

Comment: oh man this is way over my head, but i really appreciate your response nonetheless

Comment: @Anthony $k$ is the number of squares in a row. Substituting $k=2$ gives the same answer as Saketh's. You might not always want to have $2$ squares per row, in which case you need only substitute for $k$.

Comment: but in the top equation to calculate the distance from the white line on the left to the left edge of the farthest left square in the top row, we dont yet know what `n` is, so im not exactly sure how im supposed to put `(n + g) / 2` to use. also in the second one i dont know what `n` is yet so im not sure how im supposed to execute those calculations if that makes any sense?

Comment: @Anthony You're not supposed to evaluate those expressions. These expressions are used to evaluate $n$, which is given by the last expression. Note that in the last expression for $n$, all the quantities $(l,g,k)$ are known.

Comment: ohhhhhhh so the only formula to evaluate is `n = (l - ((k - 0.5) * g)) / (k + 0.5)`?

Comment: @Anthony Yes, that is right

Comment: ok now its all making sense lol. this type of math would be considered algebra? id like to learn more about it

Comment: Hmm yeah, I would consider it a word-problem in algebra-precalc

Comment: thanks. also, what does the triple dot beside the `n` symbolize/notate exactly?

Comment: It means `therefore`

Comment: thanks a lot!!! really appreciate you helping me understand all of this

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

So let's call the distance between the white lines $d$ and the gap length $g$.

**The bottom gap is centered at $x=n+0.5g$.**

**And the center of the top-"center" square is positioned at $x=d-n-g-0.5n$.**

Now, as you said, we want the gaps and the centered to be aligned.

We have an equation then.

We have $n+0.5g=d-n-g-0.5n$

**Basically, we have that $\boxed{n=0.4d-0.6g}$, where $d$ is the distance between the two white lines and g is the gap length..**

If $n$ happens to be a decimal, just round to the nearest pixel.

Comment: hmmm i might not have formatted the comparison properly because the variable should be a positive integer

Comment: ill edit my question and add more info

Comment: @Anthony of course, i'll edit my ansewr when you do

Comment: k all done. if u have any questions about what i mean or am trying to do, just ask! <3

Comment: im just gonna go have a shower. ill brb in about 20 mins

Comment: wow thats beautiful. i wish i knew how to do that. could i trouble you one last time? i put the white lines in to hopefully make it simpler for myself, but the white lines basically exclude the two gaps on the edges. this formula would still work if we were to account for the outer gaps excluded by the white lines since i can simply calculate `d` by subtracting `2g` from the total width of the dark grey area, right?

Comment: one other quick question since id really like to understand this: how did you obtain the `0.4d` and `0.6g`??

Comment: He had n+0.5g=d-n-g-0.5n

Comment: this can be rewritten as 2.5n=d-1.5g

Comment: divide by 2.5n to get

Comment: @Athony, yes $d=D-2g$

Comment: n = 0.4d - 0.6g boom

Comment: @BarryChau this is all over my head right now, but thanks anyways :D